# How to modify the CSS in vBulletin

Tags: vbulletin

One of the Occupy sites needs to make a change to the CSS of the site but doesn't know how.  Since they don't know me from adams housecat they are (thankfully reluctant to give me the keys to figure it out).  Since I've never even looked at vBulletin, so I'm hoping one of you might give some directions.  And I'll point them back to this article.

http://occupyalabama.org/forum/showthread.php?232-Improvements-to-the-CSS

**Improvements to the CSS**

Right now, we have:

```
body a {
  color: #417394;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

I'd like to see an addition of

```
div.postbody a {
  color: #2253ff;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

So that links in the posts (and only in the posts) show up more clearly.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the CSS in a file called `vbulletin-style.xml` in the `/install` directory. You can make your changes in there and then I *think* you need to reload the XML to see the changes take effect. (I haven't played with vBulletin in a while so that last part *may* be incorrect).

Comment: what do you mean from reload the xml ?